# How do I assign the most recent value in a table as a variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, we can assign values to variables like below:

```
  DECLARE @my_value INT;
  SET @my_value = 1;
```

But what if I want to assign the `MAX` of a column, say 'ColA', from `my_table`? In other words, if I do this:

```
  DECLARE @my_value INT;
  SET @my_value = SELECT (MAX([ColA])) FROM my_table;
```

I get an error. I would like to get the largest number from `my_table` and assign it to `@my_value` so that I can use it in a serial number to mark the number of times that I launched a stored procedure over its lifetime.

Thank you for your suggestions and answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @my_value INT;
SELECT @my_value = MAX([ColA]) FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot your parenthesis !

```
  DECLARE @my_value INT;
  SET @my_value = (SELECT (MAX([ColA])) FROM my_table);
```

Answer (score 1):

The most recent value in a table as a variable

```
DECLARE @my_value TABLE (value INT)
    INSERT INTO @my_value
    SELECT 1 Union ALL
    SELECT 5 Union ALL
    SELECT 1 Union ALL
    SELECT 2

    SELECT Top 1 value From
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVEr(Order by (SELECT 1))Seq,* from @my_value
    )Dt
    Order by Dt.Seq desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Finding latest value using TOP clause and order by desc

```
DECLARE @my_value INT;
SELECT TOP 1 @my_value =PatientID  FROM Patient ORDER BY PatientID DESC
SELECT  @my_value
```